# How to surpass LogManager warnings?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, logging

After compiling and running my application the following errors will be shown in my console, I have no clue how to surpass them.

```
INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) for context ''
SEVERE: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.digester.Digester).
SEVERE: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't configured the log4j logger, add a log4j.properties file in your classpath.

A basic log4j.properties file can be

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=OFF, A1

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

[Docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

Comment: thanks,how can I disable it or make it not to print the log in console?

Comment: @J888 try to set the log level to `OFF`